# Javascript/HTML/JQuery: Stop Rendering further part of the page if condition is not met

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have html code which uses bootstrap library. This code loads some part of the page and calls JavaScript methods depending on the user activity.

Now, I want to stop loading the page i.e. stop running html code if the below condition is met and show error message "xyz".

Condition: I get the value of one id from the page like var = $('a[id=abc]')[0].innerText and if some value is present, render the page or load the page otherwise show the message.

How do I write the above condition in my page.

Comment: How are you getting this "Id"?  and where are you storing it.Could you add more of your code. try looking at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103252/stop-jquery-when-condition-is-met?rq=1

Comment: so this code is on API-Management developer portal. And, just to get some info, we use above property of the page. I see this being used in other javascript methods as I said earlier which we call depending on the user activity.

Comment: @JephrenNaicker Also the above link you provided has something to do with infinite scroll event. In my case, I just want to add a message on the page if condition is met or else go forward and render entire page.

Comment: I got the answer.  $(document).ready(function(){....}) in jquery can be helpful  since page do not load by this time. I can add the condition in the function by hiding div element and showing the error message with the other div element  if condition is met else show all the div elements.  Thanks!